# Camel parallelAggregate

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'll need the `aggregate` method to be run in parallel in my split so I activated `parallelAggregate` option but it doesn't work as I expected it.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SplitAggregationTest extends CamelTestSupport {
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SplitAggregationTest.class);

@Override
protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                    .split(body(), new AggregationStrategy() {
                        @Override
                        public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                LOGGER.error("InterruptedException: ", e);
                            }
                            return oldExchange == null ? newExchange : oldExchange;
                        }
                    }).streaming().parallelProcessing().parallelAggregate()
                        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, LOGGER, "Aggreg ${body}")
                    .end();
        }
    };
}

@Test
public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Aggregate methods (in purple) are not run in parallel, they are waiting each other to finish before:

[image: Threads view]

Edit - The according thread dump :

```
"Camel (camel-2) thread #17 - Split" #36 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0   tid=0x000002317da51800 nid=0x149bc waiting on condition  [0x00000062a55fe000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x000000076e105c70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.complete(AsyncCompletionService.java:141)
at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.access$200(AsyncCompletionService.java:30)
at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.accept(AsyncCompletionService.java:168)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.lambda$null$0(MulticastProcessor.java:579)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask$$Lambda$519/1049021104.done(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback.run(AsyncCallback.java:44)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.lambda$schedule$1(MulticastProcessor.java:348)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$$Lambda$517/1626228981.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x000000076f0ca838> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"Camel (camel-2) thread #16 - Split" #35 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0   tid=0x000002317da54000 nid=0x6a8 waiting on condition [0x00000062a54fe000]
java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
at com.mybatch.camel.processor.SplitAggregationTest$1$1.aggregate(SplitAggregationTest.java:34)
at org.apache.camel.AggregationStrategy.aggregate(AggregationStrategy.java:86)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doAggregateInternal(MulticastProcessor.java:894)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doAggregate(MulticastProcessor.java:858)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastTask.aggregate(MulticastProcessor.java:451)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.lambda$null$0(MulticastProcessor.java:582)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask$$Lambda$519/1049021104.done(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback.run(AsyncCallback.java:44)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.lambda$schedule$1(MulticastProcessor.java:348)
at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$$Lambda$517/1626228981.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Locked ownable synchronizers:
- <0x000000076e105c70> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
- <0x000000076ef115b0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's define these terms first:

**parallelProcessing**: If true, Each split item will be run via threads from a thread pool, either default, or one you provide.

**parallelAggregate**: If true, Camel will **not** synchronize calls to your `AggregationStrategy` (make sure it's thread safe btw).

Based on the names of the threads you're getting, Camel is running the split items on different threads. Are you certain that your `aggregate` method is not being called concurrently by multiple threads? Perhaps what you're seeing is that **Camel waits for all split items to complete before moving past the split**.

Comment: With the thread dump I just provided, it looks like the running aggregate method is locking the others.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations (src [here](https://github.com/slever/my-camel/blob/main/src/test/java/SplitAggregationTest.java)) it appears the reentrantlock in [MulticastProcessor#agregate()](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-3.14.x/core/camel-core-processor/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/processor/MulticastProcessor.java#L447) prevents the split threads to process the `AggregationStrategy` at the same time from camel V3.X (in V2.X the same test aggregates as expected in // )

Don't you think this reentrantlock in agregate methode is not in the sense of parallelAggregate config ?

Here is the log output of the test (agregate processing during 1 sec, one after other)

```
2022-08-12 17:09:14,997|INFO |main|o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext:3116||    Started route1 (direct://start)
2022-08-12 17:09:14,997|INFO |main|o.a.c.i.e.AbstractCamelContext:3134||Apache Camel 3.14.0 (camel-1) started in 169ms (build:48ms init:114ms start:7ms)
2022-08-12 17:09:15,013|INFO |pool-1-thread-3|SplitAggregationTest:166||Split part C
2022-08-12 17:09:15,013|INFO |pool-1-thread-2|SplitAggregationTest:166||Split part A
2022-08-12 17:09:15,013|INFO |pool-1-thread-1|SplitAggregationTest:166||Split part D
2022-08-12 17:09:15,013|INFO |pool-1-thread-4|SplitAggregationTest:166||Split part B
2022-08-12 17:09:15,016|INFO |pool-1-thread-4|SplitAggregationTest:29||> Aggregate NULL to new: B:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000001
2022-08-12 17:09:16,016|INFO |pool-1-thread-1|SplitAggregationTest:29||> Aggregate B:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000001 to new: D:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000002
2022-08-12 17:09:17,016|INFO |pool-1-thread-3|SplitAggregationTest:29||> Aggregate B:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000001 to new: C:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000003
2022-08-12 17:09:18,016|INFO |pool-1-thread-2|SplitAggregationTest:29||> Aggregate B:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000001 to new: A:FCFE9D041FBDD72-0000000000000004
2022-08-12 17:09:19,016|INFO |pool-1-thread-2|SplitAggregationTest:166||End aggregation  B
```

Here the threaddump when "pool-1-thread-1" is agregating. the others 3 threads are waiting parking to wait for *ReentrantLock$NonfairSync*

```
"pool-1-thread-4" #15 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000210a1800 nid=0x5988 waiting on condition [0x000000002275e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000076bd49968> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.complete(AsyncCompletionService.java:141)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.access$200(AsyncCompletionService.java:30)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.accept(AsyncCompletionService.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.lambda$null$0(MulticastProcessor.java:579)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask$$Lambda$73/792205377.done(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback.run(AsyncCallback.java:44)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.lambda$schedule$1(MulticastProcessor.java:348)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$$Lambda$70/900268191.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000076f701340> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"pool-1-thread-3" #14 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000210a0000 nid=0x3c8c waiting on condition [0x000000002265e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000076bd49968> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.complete(AsyncCompletionService.java:141)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService.access$200(AsyncCompletionService.java:30)
        at org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.AsyncCompletionService$Task.accept(AsyncCompletionService.java:168)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.lambda$null$0(MulticastProcessor.java:579)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask$$Lambda$73/792205377.done(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback.run(AsyncCallback.java:44)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.lambda$schedule$1(MulticastProcessor.java:348)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$$Lambda$70/900268191.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000076f7011d0> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"pool-1-thread-2" #13 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000210a0800 nid=0x32f8 waiting on condition [0x000000002255f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x000000076f7010f8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - None

"pool-1-thread-1" #12 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x000000002109f000 nid=0x4770 runnable [0x000000002245e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at SplitAggregationTest$1.lambda$0(SplitAggregationTest.java:35)
        at SplitAggregationTest$1$$Lambda$30/2021707251.aggregate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.camel.AggregationStrategy.aggregate(AggregationStrategy.java:86)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doAggregateInternal(MulticastProcessor.java:894)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doAggregate(MulticastProcessor.java:858)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastTask.aggregate(MulticastProcessor.java:451)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask.lambda$null$0(MulticastProcessor.java:582)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$MulticastReactiveTask$$Lambda$73/792205377.done(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.camel.AsyncCallback.run(AsyncCallback.java:44)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor$Worker.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:187)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.DefaultReactiveExecutor.schedule(DefaultReactiveExecutor.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.lambda$schedule$1(MulticastProcessor.java:348)
        at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$$Lambda$70/900268191.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
        - <0x000000076bd49968> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
        - <0x000000076f701390> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Thanx for any help